# Shape of 1D convolution output on a 2D data using keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement a 1D convolution on a time series classification problem using keras. I am having some trouble interpreting the output size of the 1D convolutional layer.

I have my data composed of the time series of different features over a time interval of 128 units and I apply a 1D convolutional layer:

```
x = Input((n_timesteps, n_features))
cnn1_1 = Conv1D(filters = 100, kernel_size= 10, activation='relu')(x)
```

which after compilation I obtain the following shapes of the outputs:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_26 (InputLayer)        (None, 128, 9)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_28 (Conv1D)           (None, 119, 100)          9100
```

I was assuming that with 1D convolution, the data is only convoluted across the time axis (axis 1) and the size of my output would be:
119, 100*9. But I guess that the network is performing some king of  operation across the feature dimension (axis 2) and I don't know which operation is performing. 
I am saying this because what I interpret as 1d convolution is that the features shapes must be preserved because I am only convolving the time domain: If I have 9 features, then for each filter I have 9 convolutional kernels, each of these applied to a different features and convoluted across the time axis. This should return 9 convoluted features for each filter resulting in an output shape of 119, 9*100.
However the output shape is 119, 100.

Clearly something else is happening and I can't understand it or get it.

where am I failing my reasoning? How is the 1d convolution performed?

I add one more comment which is my comment on one of the answers provided:

I understand the reduction from 128 to 119, but what I don't understand is why the feature dimension changes. For example, if I use

```
Conv1D(filters = 1, kernel_size= 10, activation='relu')
```

, then the output dimension is going to be (None, 119, 1), giving rise to only one feature after the convolution. What is going on in this dimension, which operation is performed to go from from 9 --> 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Conv1D](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/) needs 3D tensor for its input with shape (`batch_size,time_step,feature`). Based on your code, the filter size is 100 which means filter converted from 9 dimensions to 100 dimensions. How does this happen? **Dot Product**.

[image]

In above, `X_i` is the concatenation of `k` words (`k` = kernel_size), `l` is number of filters (l=filters), `d` is the dimension of input word vector, and `p_i` is output vector for each window of `k` words.

*What happens in your code?*

`[n_features * 9]` dot `[n_features * 9]` => `[1]` =>  repeat `l-times` => `[1 * 100]`

do above for all sequences => `[128 * 100]`

Another thing that happens here is you did not specify the `padding` type. [According to the docs](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/), by default Conv1d use **valid** padding which caused your dimension to reduce from 128 to 119. If you need the dimension to be the same as the input you can choose the **same** option:

```
Conv1D(filters = 100, kernel_size= 10, activation='relu', padding='same')
```

Comment: I understand the reduction from 128 to 119, but what I don't understand is why the feature dimension changes. For example, if I use Conv1D(filters = 1, kernel_size= 10, activation='relu'), then the output dimension is going to be (None, 119, 1), giving rise to only one feature after the convolution. What is going on in this dimension, which operation is performed to go from from 9 --> 1?

Comment: @Iván simple matrix multiplication **xW+b** happens here. Read more [here](http://colah.github.io/posts/2014-07-Understanding-Convolutions/)

Comment: Filters = 1, features = 1

Answer (score 1):

It Sums over the last axis, which is the feature axis, you can easily check this by doing the following:

```
input_shape = (1, 128, 9)
# initialize kernel with ones, and use linear activations

y = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(1,3, activation="linear", input_shape=input_shape[2:],kernel_initializer="ones")(x)
```

y :

[image]

if you sum x along the feature axis you will get:
x

[image]

Now you can easily see that the sum of the first 3 values of sum of  x is the first value of convolution, I used a kernel size of  3 to make this verification easier